# Trying to PenTest my client's local network but their Public IP is the same as other people in the area

Tags: networking, router, ip, wan, internet-security

I posted something similar before and it was just Closed due to clarity. So I've updated it and added clarity and changed the title.

I had posted on Stack's Network Engineering but apparently I was not smart enough so they told me to come to SuperUser but maybe I'm not even smart enough for here, considering my previous question was just closed and not left open for comment.

Plus, it said I could edit my question but...it still seems to be closed to any comments.
[Why is my WAN/Public IP the same as my neighbor's? Trying to PenTest](https://superuser.com/questions/1657850/why-is-my-wan-public-ip-the-same-as-my-neighbors-trying-to-pentest?noredirect=1#comment2538144_1657850)

EDIT--- I am using established PenTest scenarios that might be used by a hacker to get into a network. With all of the ransomware problems I worry that they might target my client. I tried posting this on Network Engineering, since I'm trying to lock down a business client's network.

The problem I'm encountering is that IF the ISP is using CGN, is there a way to circumvent that? As I mention below, I imagine that a proficient hacker can get around that in some way.

The main question is, how do you PenTest a network under these circumstances? Apparently this is too basic for Network Engineering so they sent me here. So let's assume I'm trying to be a SuperUser but I'm not there yet, where do I start? It doesn't really help to just close my post, asking for more detail. I feel I provided enough detail for this situation. Is there a NotSuperUser site I should go to? I've already been downgraded from Network Engineering to SuperUser and now you are saying my question isn't even valid here.

Please tell me what other site I can go to for help if you can't help me here. Or tell me how much more detail I need to provide. I already said I can't PenTest a router because it has the same IP as every other router in the area likely due to the ISP using CGN. But it still needs to be tested. There must be a way to test these networks. The fact that we have to test these networks means that all the things that are in place are not secure, including CGN.

I didn't want to mention this because I felt it was an issue with ISP and not relevant to this discussion, but... I did a test on the "Public IP" and it indicated vulnerabilities, mainly lighthttpd. That's not likely a problem on my client's router. But, because I can't test my client's router specifically I don't know for sure. I have contacted the ISP but they only work M-F. But the point is, I need to test my client's router for problems, outside of the ISP. That was my question, how to test a router hidden behind a CGN, if possible.

I hope that was enough clarification. ---EDIT

Hello and thank you in advance for any assistance. I'm new to this side of Stack. I tried posting this in Network Engineering but even thought I'm working on a commercial client's network it was off-topic and they suggested I post here.

To start, I was wanting to do some Penetration Testing for a client. The client is a small office, not a home network. I'm starting with some very basic things. The most basic is pentest-tools website. I wanted to start by testing this at home because their network it not like some Google corporate network. The use off the shelf hardware. But today when I went to get their "Public/WAN" IP address, so that after I'd tested my own network I could test theirs remotely. What I found, using whatismyip, is that we both have the same public address.

I did read a few articles about CGN on NE and that is likely the case for me. (from this article here. https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/30184/is-my-dynamic-ip-address-provided-by-my-isp-shared ) I tried using the tool listed but it is a bit outdated.

My tracert shows this at the beginning. The public IP I get does start with 98.163 but it is not the same as the one shown in tracert. When I do ipconfig, in Windows, my gateway is the first hop here.

```
  1     1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  192.168.1.1
  2     1 ms     1 ms     1 ms  192.168.10.1
  3     5 ms     4 ms     3 ms  10.4.x.254
  4     6 ms     4 ms     6 ms  98.163.xx.x
```

My first concern is, how do I PenTest their local network remotely, or basically as if I were a hacker, if I can't get to their router directly, or is this not something I should not worry about with CGN? ie, it's not even possible to do and I should just worry about someone who gets onto their local network using a provided WiFi access code. I really can't imagine that is the case for an experienced hacker, they must know their way around CGN.

Thanks in advance and please excuse my ignorance.

Regards, Dewi

Comment: Not sure about where you are, but this network setup seems uncommon. How are you obtaining the company's IP address, and how are you verifying they are the same?

Comment: Also, if you are truly behind the same CGN, you should be able to scan the company router's "external" address from there.

Comment: I'm in the mountains of Arizona and the internet access is PTP Wireless. I'm wanting to PenTest at the Community Center and when I checked their IPv4 address it was the same as mine at home. We both use the same internet provider. Right now I can only check the IP using whatismyip. I didn't set up the router and no one knows the password to get into it, except the company likely, and they only take emergency calls on the weekend. So I can't double check it right now. Just trying to get as much info as possible for when they call. I've never encountered this type of internet before, the IP part